# Adding takeUntil stops triggering all the actions rxJS, redux-observable

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

I'm trying to figure out a way to cancel all the HTTP request once the user logs out.
I've created a generic function that is responsible for creating the ajax request. This is the function

```
const createRequest = (ajaxParameters) => {
  return ajax(ajaxParameters).pipe(
    takeUntil([ofType("LOGOUT")])
  )
};
```

and all of my epic functions are importing the above function to make the HTTP request. I'm doing something like this

```
   const sendRequest = (url) => {
       xhr = createRequest(_.merge({}, requestDefaults, {
             method: "GET",
             url: url
          }, token))
      xhr.pipe(
          map( 
             // some code over here and triggering some actions over here
          )
      )
   }
```

The problem is whenever I add `takeUntil` like the way I did above it stops triggering all of the epics. Any idea what is it that I'm doing wrong over here?

epic code

```
const fetchUserData = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(user.FETCH_USER_DATA.PENDING),
  mergeMap(sendRequest(URL_OVER_HERE))
);
```

---

Comment: You usually don't need to complete the requests with `takeUntil` because when you logout you should destroy all components and these components should unsubscribe. Can you show one of your epics that don't work any more?

Comment: @martin I've added the epic code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `[ofType("LOGOUT")]` is doing there, but most-likely, what you want is to `pipe` off `action$`:

```
const createRequest = (ajaxParameters) => {
  return ajax(ajaxParameters).pipe(
    takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType("LOGOUT")))
  )
};
```

`takeUntil` completes your observable if it receives a value. The way you have it, it probably thinks the array is an observable and the value is the operator `ofType`. So it completes before anything even starts. That's why you have to listen to `action$` instead.

As another optimization, you can immediately `pipe` off the `xhr` observable:

```
const sendRequest = (url) => {
  createRequest(_.merge({}, requestDefaults, {
    method: "GET",
    url: url
  }, token))
  .pipe(
    map( 
      // some code over here and triggering some actions over here
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: Sawtaytoes the problem with this solution is  `takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType("LOGOUT")))` I don't have action$ variable available over here. Due to which I cannot do the way you mentioned. 

Secondly, I've created generic get, post etc request. All the epics import request object from one file and then do the work they need to do

Comment: once thing which I can do is this `takeUntil(from(ofType("LOGOUT")))` but this also does not helps

Comment: That won't work either. `ofType` is an operator. You need to pass in `action$`. If you want something truly generic, use an action. `AJAX_GET` and then do your AJAX call in there.

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply, but is it possible for you to give an example